# Explicit cast in expression tree?

Tags: c#

Consider the `MyDecimal` class below. In `C#` we can cast it to an integer thanks to the implicit `decimal` operator:

```
int i = (int)new MyDecimal(123m);
```

**How do you produce the equivalent code in an expression tree?**

When using [Expression.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) (`.NET 4.5.1`) it immediately fails with `No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int32' and 'MyDecimal'`. It seems to only consider implicit cast operators.

```
try
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), null);
    var convert = Expression.Convert(param, typeof(MyDecimal));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

`MyDecimal` class:

```
public class MyDecimal
{
    private readonly decimal value;

    public MyDecimal(decimal value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(MyDecimal myDecimal)
    {
        return myDecimal.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyDecimal(decimal value)
    {
        return new MyDecimal(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) {}` -- please, please, don't do that.

Comment: @Heinzi - is `catch(Exception) {}` any better <):O)

Comment: I think what @Heinzi means is that you should probably record the exception details: e.g. `catch(Exception ex) { Console.Write(ex); }`.

Comment: @Heinzi Having `ex` makes it easier for you to look at the exception in your debugger. In my production code I have `catch {}` if that makes you happier :)

Comment: @l33t: Sorry, I was not clear enough - I thought it was obvious, but it apparently isn't: Having `ex` is perfectly fine! It's the `{}` part that bothered me, it's the "try-catch-ignore" anti-pattern. All it does is make debugging a nightmare. The correct solution is to remove `try` and the catch block altogether. (Yes, there are situations where "swallowing exceptions" is correct, but they are *extremely rare*, usually only cover a single line of code and need to be *extensively* documented. Nothing in your question indicates that this is warranted here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always interesting to example the expression tree of an Expression Lambda that does the same thing:

```
Expression<Func<MyDecimal,int>> convert = m => (int)m;
```

Using a tool link LinqPad we can examine convert and see we have the following:

```
Expression<Func<MyDecimal,int>> (type: Lambda)
|
+-  UnaryExpression (type:Convert) - Convert(int, decimal)
    |
    +- UnaryExpression (type:Convert) - Convert(decmal, MyDecimal)
```

So, although the **compiler** allows the implicit conversion from `decimal` to `int`, you can see that the equivalent `Lambda` requires the conversion to be explicit.

***EDIT***

So, to construct the complete expression, you've have something like:

```
        Expression.Assign(
            Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "i"),
            Expression.Convert(
                Expression.Convert(
                    Expression.New(
                        typeof(MyDecimal).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(decimal)}),
                        Expression.Convert(
                            Expression.Constant(1),
                            typeof(decimal)
                        )
                    ),
                    typeof(decimal)),
                typeof(int)
            )
        )
```

Some points to note:

- We're converting the `int` 1 to `decimal` to pass to the constructor
- We have to look up the constructor with the correct type parameters (I'm cheating and assuming it's public)
- We're assuming `i` is already declared.

Comment: Using two `Expression.Convert` solves the problem when the type is known to be `typeof(int)`. I'm wondering if your code can be improved to handle an arbitrary `Type` object. E.g. `Type t = myObj.GetType()` where `myObj` would be either `int` or `decimal`.

Comment: @l33t - that's surely a different question? You'd probably have to check for a valid conversion to a .Net Base Type, and then do the casting from there. It might be helpful to know how you intend to use this code in a wider context, as there may be a simpler solution.

Comment: @l33t - also, look at the `IConvertible` interface (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Convert.ChangeType` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) - they have the potential to simplify the whole process.